# Flow(InferError): Cannot call await with 'axios.get(...)' bound to 'p'

Tags: axios, flowtype

I'm getting some Flow errors using axios.

```
Cannot call await with 'axios.get(...)' bound to 'p' because:
Either property 'error_message' is missing in 'AxiosXHR'. 
Or property 'data' is missing in 'Promise'
```

Here is my code, with an attempted type annotation. (Same error without the `AxiosPromise<Object>` annotation.) The error is on `axios.get(url)`.

```js
  async handleAddressChange(): AxiosPromise<Object> {
    const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=${GoogleMapsApiKey}&input=${this.state.address}`;
    try {
      const { data, error_message } = await axios.get(url);
      if (error_message) throw Error(error_message);
      this.setState({
        addressPredictions: data.predictions,
        showPredictions: true
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  }
```

Funny thing is that in another file axios gives no Flow problems:

```js
export async function loginWithApi(creds: AuthParams) {
  const res = await axios.get(ApiUrls.login, { params: creds });
  return res.data;
}
```

I have `import type { AxiosPromise, $AxiosXHR } from "axios";` in my file.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of error there will be no `error_message` in [returned payload](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/axios_v0.18.x/flow_v0.93.x-/axios_v0.18.x.js#L71), but the error goes into the `catch` block.

Also, the `handleAddressChange` does not returns `AxiosPromise`, instead it returns implicit `promise`, as it defined with `async`

So, something like this:

```
async handleAddressChange(): Promise<void> {
const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=${GoogleMapsApiKey}&input=${this.state.address}`;
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(url);
      this.setState({
        addressPredictions: data.predictions,
        showPredictions: true
      });
    } catch (err: AxiosError) {
      new Error(err);
    }
  }
```

Might work for you. Note the [AxiosError](http://AxiosError) definition.

One extra note is that you can add returned payload into the `AxiosPromise` generic, i.e.:

```
type TExpectedLoginResponse = {
    ok: boolean,
    token: string
}

export async function loginWithApi(creds: AuthParams): AxiosPromise<TExpectedLoginResponse> {
  const res = await axios.get(ApiUrls.login, { params: creds });
  return res.data; // so now flow knows that res.data is type of TExpectedLoginResponse
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That first suggestion is basically good, except the google maps API returns an `error_message` when, for example, the request succeeds but a search is empty; so I don't think it would throw an error. What I did to fix this is: 
`const { data, ...res } = await axios.get(url);      
if (res.error_message) throw Error(res.error_message);`
Flow seems okay with the rest parameter, so I can get the `error_message` from there.

Comment: @JonathanTuzman this looks strange to me - if `error_message` is part of response body, then  it should be in `data`, no?